# SQL - Selecting the most occurring value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple database consisting of these tables. Here I am trying to write a query to select the player who played in the most games from the Games table.

Just by looking at the below example you can tell that the answer is Ben of course, because PID 2 (which is Ben from the Players table) appears the most times in the Games table, meaning Ben won the most games.

But I am not sure how to write the query for selecting the most recurring value in the Games table.

```
Players         Games          

PID | name      GID | PID
----|-----      ----|------
1   |  Al       A   |  3
2   |  Ben      A   |  2
3   |  Carl     A   |  2
4   |  Jack     A   |  1
5   |  Ron      A   |  4
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: what is the relation between Players and Games table?

Comment: *"The answer is Ben of course"* It's not immediately obvious for me. How do you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: It looks better now, but how is the Positions table relevant here?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity I realized I made a mistake in writing the table. So we have on the Games table 1 game played, Game ID is A for this game, players on this table are listed under PID. Therefore the player who played the most games can be seen here (which should be PID of 2) this maps on the Players table and PID 2 is Ben

Comment: @NullUserException it is a table that I have, I thought it might help in this case but as you pointed out it is not relevant I will remove it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, join players and games, count, group by player, order by count desc (greatest first), and limit to one if you want the first.

```
SELECT p.NID, p.name, COUNT(*)
FROM Players p
INNER JOIN Games g ON g.PID= p.NID
GROUP BY p.NID, p.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there's no counting to be done, just a simple integer value in the Games table indicating the number of games for a player ID...

```
SELECT pl.name FROM Players pl join Games g ON pl.NID=g.GID
ORDER BY g.games DESC
limit 1;
```